# Invoking a generic interface's method through reflection invokes a method from a base implementation of the same interface in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection, system.reflection

I have the following generic interface:

```
public interface IGenericInterface<T>
{
    public void PrintGenericParameterTypeName()
    {
        Debug.Log($"Generic parameter type: {typeof(T).Name}");
    }
}
```

I then have the following classes:

```
public class Base : MonoBehaviour, IGenericInterface<int>
{
}
```

```
public class Derived : Base, IGenericInterface<string>
{
}
```

I have an instance of type `Derived` in my scene. When I run this code, I **correctly** get both of its generic interfaces (`IGenericInterface<string>` and `IGenericInterface<int>`)

```
var derived = FindObjectOfType<Derived>();

var derivedType = derived.GetType();

var derivedTypeGenericInterfaces =
    derivedType.GetInterfaces()
    .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IGenericInterface<>));
```

However, when invoking the `PrintGenericParameterTypeName` method for each of the interfaces, both times the method from the base class's interface implementation is invoked (`IGenericInterface<int>`).

```
foreach (var genericInterface in derivedTypeGenericInterfaces)
{
    var printMethod = genericInterface.GetMethod("PrintGenericParameterTypeName");
    printMethod?.Invoke(derived, null);
}
```

Recreating this in a console application (the only difference being the `Base` class does not inherit from anything) works as expected and the method is once invoked for `IGenericInterface<string>` and once for `IGenericInterface<int>`. In Unity, however, both times the method is invoked for `IGenericInterface<int>`. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Changing the default interface method's return type to its generic type `T` seems to have fixed the problem.

```
public T PrintGenericParameterTypeName()
{
    Debug.Log($"Generic parameter type: {typeof(T).Name}");
    return default;
}
```

And I am now getting the expected results.
But I still have no explanation for this unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the implementation out of interface to the base class.  Something like this...

```
public interface IGenericInterface<T>
{
    abstract void PrintGenericParameterTypeName();
    
}
public class Base : IGenericInterface<int>
{
    public void PrintGenericParameterTypeName()
    {
        Console.Write($"Generic parameter type: {typeof(T).Name}");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base, IGenericInterface<string>
{
}
```

Then call it like this...

```
    foreach (var i in derivedTypeGenericInterfaces)
{
    i.InvokeMember("PrintGenericParameterTypeName",
        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
        BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,  derived, new object[] {});
}
```

Comment: This would probably work, but not for me. I am not looking to change my implementation as I've designed it around the use of a default interface method. I'm simply trying to understand why it's not working as expected.

Comment: @GeorgiTonchev - I'm not a unity expert - but I know that the engine wires up the MonoBehavior and associated interfaces inherited on the object with a native Mono/CPP binding method that isn't dotnet reflection.  I suspect it's causing the issue.  I doubt it will help, but it the code above I just added works for you - give it a try.  I don't have an environment to run a test so it's a Hail Mary - sorry.